# How can I get when a webservice does not respond due to internet connection problems

Tags: javascript, connection, webservice-client

As in title I have a page that calls a lot of webservices through JavaScript to get several infos in client side.

I have inserted a counter++ in every webservice call and a counter-- in webservice respond methods or in the webserviceFail method. I tested it a lot and everything worked fine.

I show a msg to the user to wait till all the info came from the server and when counter is 0 he can submit the form. In test environment everything was ok and the testes passed all. In a specific client (that has not a good internet connection), happens that even if he wait for long the msg remain, means that some webservice didn't respond or didn't returned to webserviceFail method.

Is this possible? Is there a timeout for the webservice, and after the timeout expired does it return on the webserviceFail method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is a case when a webservice doesn't response if I can say that. When you call a webservice be sure to surround it with try catch, when the webservice is called and some parameter is NaN and the webservice expect an int, it is thrown and exception in client side because NaN can't be serialized. By this way the server doesn't receive nothing so I will not return in the fail function in clientside.